# Restrict text field to allow only letters or a space to be entered

Tags: workflow, validation

I have created a custom text field (Text01__c).

I need a way of allowing ONLY the characters [a-z][A-Z] and space.

Can someone help me with either a formula or workflow rule to prevent this text field from saving with any other characters?

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: What is your question? 'Any formula for validation rule or workflow rule'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below validation rule

NOT(REGEX( Text01__c, "[a-zA-Z ]*$"))

Comment: Thank it working fine.It not allows any special characters.

Comment: I hope this is the functionality you want

Comment: Or, NOT(REGEX(Text01__c, "^(\\w\\s)*$")) if you want to allow other "word" characters, such as "ñ", which would be common in Spanish words.

Answer (score -3):

You can try below regular expression

```
'^[a-zA-Z\s]+$'
```

Comment: Hi Ajay. Welcome to SF.SE. You may not be aware, but you've posted a reply to a 1-1/2 y.o. question that has an accepted answer. Further, your answer is incomplete and provides a regular expression that wouldn't work with Salesforce validation rules. I recommend you visit our [Help] to learn how this forum works before posting further.